# SQL Server nested query for time offset

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, timezone-offset

I am trying to offset the time in the column based on the time zone. I am trying to use this:

```
SELECT 
    SERIAL_NUMBER,
    CONVERT(datetime, TIME_FROM)
      AT TIME ZONE ('US Eastern Standard Time')
FROM 
    tmp_TestZone
```

which returns what I need, however each row in my table has record with specific time zone which can be any time zone. What I have to do is to replace 'US Eastern Standard Time' with a nested query that will pull the correct time zone for particular serial number. Time zone is stored in the last column which is `TIMEZONE_LU.TZ`

My table looks like this:

```
  ,[IP_ADDRESS]
  ,[NAME]
  ,[GROUP_NAME]
  ,[DEVICE_TYPE]
  ,[LINE_NAME]
  ,[DATE_FROM]
  ,[TIME_FROM]
  ,[TIME_TO]
  ,[fw]
  ,[bw]
  ,[SITE_NAME]
  ,[TZ]
```

I tried to build the query like this:

```
SELECT
    SERIAL_NUMBER,
    CONVERT(datetime, TIME_FROM)
        AT TIME ZONE (SELECT TZ
                      FROM tmp_TestZone) NEW_TIME
FROM 
    tmp_TestZone
```

But I'm getting an error:

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>   Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

How do I fix this?

The suggestion:

```
SELECT
SERIAL_NUMBER,
CONVERT(datetime, TIME_FROM)
    AT TIME ZONE (SELECT TZ
                  FROM tmp_TestZone) NEW_TIME
FROM 
tmp_TestZone
```

Would work however i just found that my timezones are not standardized. 
I am going to try to use

```
  SELECT SERIAL_NUMBER,
  SWITCHOFFSET(TIME_FROM, '-05:00')
   FROM tmp_TestZone2
```

Could you help me to replace '-05:00' from above code so ti reads values from UTC_offset column which are in exact format as '-05:00'

Thank you so much

Ok so here is the table:

```
SELECT [SERIAL_NUMBER]
  ,[IP_ADDRESS]
  ,[NAME]
  ,[GROUP_NAME]
  ,[DEVICE_TYPE]
  ,[LINE_NAME]
  ,[DATE_FROM]
  ,[TIME_FROM]
  ,[TIME_TO]
  ,[fw]
  ,[bw]
  ,[SITE_NAME]
  ,[TZ]
  ,[CC]
  ,[UTC_offset]
  ,[UTC_DST_offset]
```

FROM [VHA].[dbo].[tmp_TestZone2]

And here is the data of that table:
[image]

I have the columns TIME_FROM and TIME_TO that needs to be offset for UTC_Offset values. 
So for the instance in the picture TIME_FROM (10:10:00) and TIME_TO (11:00:00) should be offset for -7:00 and so on for every row the TIME_FROM and TIME_TO should be offset for what ever value is in column UTC_Offset.

Comment: You need to add a `where` clause to your sub-query to select a specific row.

Comment: @marc_s,im not sure how would i add where clause like that, because it would need to refer to every row with serial number.

Comment: @Slavisha: Did you try my below answer?

Comment: @im_one, yes and it works however it tells me that my timezones are not standardized they are called with different abbreviation. So i have to try using switchoffset function. I just posted updated question in original post.

Comment: @Slavisha: Could you please mention your sql-server version?

Comment: @im_one, Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 14.0.17289.0 this is Developer version v17.9.1. The timezones in that columns comes from outside source which is why they are not standardized. My options is to go through each of them and try to standardize them or try to just use the offset column.

Comment: @Slavisha: Not client version. Please run this query 'select @@version' and let me know your sql-server database version. So i can provide you certain answer

Comment: @im_one, This is the output i got: Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (RTM-CU2) (KB3182270) - 13.0.2164.0 (X64)   Sep  9 2016 20:13:26   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Express Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard 6.3 <X64> (Build 9600: ) (Hypervisor)

Comment: @Slavisha: I am not getting your edited question about suggestion. So could you please show your Expected output format in the question?

Comment: @im_one, i updated the response, i hope it makes sense. As i mentioned i cant use column TZ since the values in it are not standardized so i have to use UTC_Offset column somehow.

Comment: @Slavisha: Please try updated answer. let me know in comment if you have any issue!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try like this**

```
SELECT
    SERIAL_NUMBER,
    CONVERT(datetime, TIME_FROM)
        AT TIME ZONE temp.tz
FROM 
    tmp_TestZone AS temp;
```

This may help you.

***Edited Question's answer***:

If I understood your question correctly then please try below query to remove your Time Offset from the result...

```
SELECT SERIAL_NUMBER,
CONVERT(varchar(19),SWITCHOFFSET(TIME_FROM, '-05:00'),120) AS Result_date
FROM tmp_TestZone2
```

***OR***

```
SELECT SERIAL_NUMBER,
CONVERT(varchar(19),SWITCHOFFSET(TIME_FROM, UTC_offset),120) AS Result_date
FROM tmp_TestZone2
```

Maintain `varchar(19)` length according your `DATETIME CONVERSION CODE` (like `120`).

Comment: @is_one, this will only resolve it for records where the offset is -5, but timezones for each serial number vary which is why i need to use something like variable instead of '-05:00'. So for example if my serial number 1234 is in time zone -7, it has to offset for -7, if the next serial number in the row below is 5678 and offset is +3 it has to offset for +3. So I have to make that work for all 6k rows without me typing literaly -7 or +3 or -5 for each row.

Comment: @Slavisha: you can replace "-05:00" by your column name "[UTC_offset]"  in my last updated query. Still you have problem to get an output? Then please let me know your  "[UTC_offset]" Column DataType

Comment: thank you for response, When i run the query i get this message:
"Msg 9812, Level 16, State 0, Line 29
The timezone provided to builtin function switchoffset is invalid. "
i am assuming that data type is the issue now. Curently the UTC_offset is stored as nvarchar(50).

Comment: @Slavisha: 'nvarchar' is not the issue! please try something else. you can check demo here https://rextester.com/ELUF54986

Comment: thank you for all your help. I made it work based on your suggestion. You are lifesaver.

Comment: @is_one how do i offset the date now? Offsetting the time was perfect. However it happens that when i load date it offsets for day after or day before depends of the time zone and the time for which sensor run the data. In your example above, how do i modify it so it offsets the date as separate column?